# SpringBatch: getting the executionid of a completed instance by its JobParameters

Tags: spring-batch

My software is coreographing a number of spring batch jobs. The output of a job is partially an input for the next job . It may happen that the entire process (the entire jobs chain) is restarted, even if one or more jobs in the chain have been successfully completed. In this case, when I try tu run one of the jobs again with the same parameters, I get a JobInstanceAlreadyCompletedException as expected. I could skip and go on to the next job but I would need to access the context of the completed instance in order to get the output produced by its steps and pass them over to the next job.

According to the JobExplorer APIs, this is just possible if you have the executionId of the completed instance. I can't get it from the JobInstanceAlreadyCompletedException , and it looks there are no APIs for getting it from the already used parameters list. Do you know a way to get this executionId given the parameters? Or to get access, in whatever way, to the completed instance job context?

Answer (score 0):

Why not put all this jobs into one main job and using JobSteps to integrate the jobs? This way, already completed subjobs will be treated as completed steps, which will not be started again. Moreover, all information is available in the job/step contexts, even if you restart?

Another way would be to save all needed parameters and information into a file and use this to start the next job instead of beeing dependent on the Jobexecution info. Your last step could simply be a tasklet, that writes an appropriate property file.

Comment: I can't stream it in a unique/single spring batch macro job since the single jobs are running in different network zones and I have security contraints that does not allow to do this (even if I wanted. Let's say it's technically possible but I would violate some company policy...)

Comment: About your second suggestion. You basically suggest to dump all of the job produced information togheter with the job instance parameters values in a storage system (i.e a file) and get access to that using the parameters values as keys to get back the produced information at the second run request?

Comment: As far as I understood, you need control information which have to be exchanged between the different jobs on different systems/security zones. As I understood further, some of this information are normally available as jobparameters or data in the jobexecution/stepexecution. Trying to get this information out of the Batch_ tables looks a little bit awkward to me. Exchanging this information either by a kind of property file that is accessible by the other jobs or even a special table on your db sounds easier to me. A tasklet at the start and one at the end  get the job done.